# how to Search specific cell in Pandas through a list of matching content

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I am new to python and trying to make a small program with python. 
My requirement :
I have a list like this:
holiday = ['1 January 2018','26 January 2018','2 March 2018','30 March 2018']

and I have a pandas DataFrame which print like this:
[image]

Now I want to search for the Dates in dataframe which match with my list like "26 January 2018" and want to save that search result in a separate data frame.

I am not getting the proper way to do this. pls suggest

Comment: paste the code for the dataframe pls

Comment: also please indent your code and make your post readable

Answer (score 2):

**1. String matching**

If your date formats match, you can directly go for string matching (although it's a crude way)

```
df2 = df[df['date'].isin(holiday)]
```

**2. Parsing datetime (proper way)**

Parse the dates first and then go for the match!

*a. Parse the df dates*

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d %B %Y')
```

*b. Parse the dates in the list*

```
import datetime as dt
holiday = ['1 January 2018','26 January 2018','2 March 2018','30 March 2018']
holiday_parsed = [dt.strptime(i, format='%d %B %Y') for i in holiday]
```

And then do the filtering -

```
df2 = df[df['date'].isin(holiday_parsed)]
```

The `.isin()` is a pandas convenience method that lets you search your pandas series with a list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could also find an one more easy way to filter like this:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
holiday=df[df["date"].isin(['1 January 2018','26 January 2018','2 March 2018','30 March 2018','15 August 2018','22 August 2018',
               '2 October 2018','19 October 2018', '7 November 2018','8 November 2018','9 November 2018','25 December 2018'])]

Comment: @Jagdish what you did basically the same thing. I just put the list in a variable and you put the list directly

Comment: Thanks Vivek, I got it. Can you please help me on a another issue posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48668501/9325592

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method

```
holiday = ['1 January 2018','26 January 2018','2 March 2018','30 March 2018']
df.query('date==@holiday')
```

Comment: good one! what is the minimum version of pandas reqd for this?

Comment: I was working on the latest stable release so I suppose that would work. Sorry but I don;t know the minimum required version

Comment: The `inplace` parameter is a 0.18 version addition, so I guess it will run 0.18 and above if not more...